# Attempting to delete an initializer list constructor does not always take effect

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, initializer-list

Sorry for the generic title, but it's a mindfu*k situation, which I can't easily describe.

Suppose the following code:

```
struct S
{
    S() = default;

    int x;
    int y;
};

S f()
{
    return { 1, 2 };
}
```

This compiles and works perfectly fine. I want to forbid it, as it's bug prone (the actual code is far more complex). So, I tried adding

```
template<typename T>
S(std::initializer_list<T>) = delete;
```

but guess what - nothing changes. Tested on Visual Studio 2019 with std=c++17. The C++ resharper shows this as an error, but msvc actually compiles this and it works.

Wait, now it gets interesting. If `S() = default;` is replaced with `S() {}`, the compilation fails with

```
'S::S<int>(std::initializer_list<int>)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

OK, this looks like something to do with user-defined constructors and initialization?! Messy, but kinda understandable.

But wait - it gets even more interesting - keeping the `= default` constructor, **but** making the fields `private` also alters this behavior and guess what - the error has nothing to do with inaccessible members, but it again shows the error from above!

So, in order to make this deletion work, I should either make the fields private or define my own empty constructor (ignore the uninitialized x and y fields, this is just a simplified example), meaning:

```
struct S
{
    S() = default;
    // S() {}

    template<typename T>
    S(std::initializer_list<T>) = delete;

private:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

clang 13 and GCC 11 behave exactly the same way, while GCC 9.3 fails to compile the original code (with `=default` constructor, public fields, but deleted initializer list constructor).

Any ideas what happens?

Comment: What happens if you change MSVC to compile using C++20?  In C++17, `S` is considered an aggregate, and you are using aggregate initialization instead of calling any sort of constructor

Comment: @NathanOliver - you're right, C++20 complains about this.

Comment: So, what should be the proper way to forbid this then? And why does `public`/`private` modifies this behavior?

Comment: The access specifier of all members of an aggregate need to be the same.  Having them be different means your class is no longer an aggregate.  If you can live with the member being private, then I would just do that.  If you can use C++20, then even better.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks, can you post an answer? I'll accept it, makes perfect sense. It's insane though.

Comment: So, can we say this is a bug in gcc 9.3? @NathanOliver

Comment: When you compiled with GCC, did you specify the language standard?  IIRC, by default it uses C++14, and in C++14 `S` is also not considered an aggregate.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, I compiled with `g++ --std=c++17 ./test.cpp` and `gcc --version` show 9.3

Comment: Most likely that is a bug/feature not implemented in that version of GCC.  GCC10 and 11 will compile the code in C++17 mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++17, `S` is considered an aggregate, and because of that you are not calling any constructor, you are basically directly initializing the members.  If you change to using C++20, `S` is no longer considered an aggregate as the rules were changes and the code will work as expected.

The reason changing the access specifier works is that the access specifier of all non-static data members of an aggregate needs to be public. Having them be non-public means your class is no longer an aggregate, and you no longer get aggregate initialization, but instead it tries to do list initialization and fails for the deleted constructor.

Comment: By "all members" you mean all, right - not only data, but data + functions? Then shouldn't adding the deleted constructor in a private section also work? Because it changes nothing in VS.

Comment: @KirilKirov I misspoke.  Only the non-static data members need to be public

Comment: Ahaa, thanks, it make sense.

Comment: @KirilKirov I've made some recent edits, corrections.  The non-static data members need to be public to be an aggregate.  It doesn't care about the access specifier of any of the constrcutors.